# why typing into cat >&0 not not perform infinite loop

Tags: bash, redirect

As I see it, 'cat' should read standard input, which it prints itself, read it and print again and again ...  but it doesn't, <strike>what the ***</strike> why?

```
root@devel:~# cat >&0
test
test
test 2
test 2
^C
root@devel:~#
```

Answer (score 0):

Before the redirection, fd 1 is /dev/tty. After the redirection, it is *still* /dev/tty. It's the terminal itself, not the file descriptor mappings, that determine what to do with its input and output.